# how to write a file on a web server using WebClient

Tags: silverlight, webserver

I am using the following code to write a simple file to a web server in an asynchronous (Silverlight 4) context:

```
    public void WriteToServerAsync(string _input, Uri _uri, Action<bool> _writeComplete)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_input);
        var inputStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        client.OpenWriteCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            var bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                e.Result.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            e.Result.Close();
        };
        client.WriteStreamClosed += (s, e) =>
        {
            _writeComplete(e.Error == null);
        };
        client.OpenWriteAsync(_uri);
    }
```

I am calling it with

```
    public void TestWriteToServer()
    {
        var uri = new Uri( GetAppSetting( "MLCalculations" ) );
        WriteToServerAsync("This is some stuff to write", uri, (b) =>
        {
            // All done!
        });
    }
```

The string returned from the GetAppSetting call looks like

```
http://servername/MainDirectory/Writeable/TestFile.txt
```

The problem I encounter is in the client.WriteStreamClosed event handler, where e.Error has "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

On the web server, there is a file structure C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainDirectory\Writeable.  Security on the MainDirectory folder says IIS_IUSRS has Full control and the Writeable folder does, too, although the checkmarks on the MainDirectory are bold and on Writeable they are dimmed.

I also tried placing an "original" file into the target directory, in case it was a "create" issue", but I got the same result.

I do not have any trouble with WebClient.OpenReadAsync.
What am I missing?

Comment: is the `IIS_IUSRS` the app pool name for your Silverlight web site? If not, can you try to give full permission to the app pool for this virtual directory?

Comment: Application pool:  Default App Pool

Comment: According to the Application Pools, the Identity that belongs to DefaultAppPool is ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

The dimmed checks on your folder permission simply mean that those permissions are inherited from the parent folder.

9 times out of 10, the infamous "Not Found" error is caused by an exception server side. If you check out your IIS logs, you will probably be able to track down an entry with a status-code of 500 (server error).

Can you debug the web service? If not, can you edit it to provide additional tracing.
The error is almost certainly caused by an exception in the service itself, so once you have traced the error server-side, you will be well on the way.

If you cant figure it out, perhaps you can post the code for the web service?